# Angular JS does not call get data function

Tags: angularjs

Here i am using simple dropdown which calls GetEmployeeData on ng-change

```
 <select ng-options="year for year in $scope.years " name="year" ng-model="$scope.year" ng-change="$scope.GetEmployeeData()">
    </select>
```

GetEmployee Data

```
$scope.GetEmployeeData = function () {

        $scope.searchMethod = getdata;
    }
```

This get employee data function calls get data. But its is not invoked for some reason.

```
   function getdata() {
            return angularService.GetData(criteria, $scope.year, $scope.selectedYearType.name);
        }
```

Am I missing anything

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: no errors in console

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `getData` as a function, you're assigning it to `$scope.searchMethod` instead. Call `getaData` like so `getData()`.